# How do I click on the next instance of an element that has the same attributes with another element in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on an element in the same group, that has the same attributes names and values.

I wanna click on the second td tag from this code:

```
<table id="FolderIcons" class="mstrLargeIconView">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="mstrLargeIconView" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
            <td class="mstrLargeIconView" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can click on the first element with this code:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@rowspan='1']"))).click()
```

So, How can I click on the second element with the same attribute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
td1=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="FolderIcons"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]'))).click()
    
    
td2=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="FolderIcons"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]'))).click()
```